# SQL - Get highest rated movie by genre

Tags: sql, database, hsqldb

I have three tables:

```
    CREATE TABLE Movie
    (
        movieId INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
        title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        moviePath VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL
    );

    CREATE TABLE Rating
    (
        rid INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
        mid INTEGER FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Movie(movieId) ON DELETE CASCADE, 
        uid INTEGER FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES User(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
        rating INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    );

   CREATE TABLE Genre(
       id INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
       movieId INTEGER NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Movie(movieId) ON DELETE CASCADE,
       genre VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
   );
```

I want to create an sql query which gives me the most seen movie(with moviepath, title) from the the most seen genre back.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

Results:

```
| MID |   TITLE    | MOVIEPATH |
--------------------------------
|   4 | Happy days |         a |
|   4 | Happy days |         a |
```

Comment: I think `movieId` should not be in `Genre` table, but a `GenreId` should be in `Movie` table. And your table is incomplete for such a query, you need some additional details.

Comment: with your current table each genre can have one movie, but with the tables I told each film has one genre.

Comment: @MahdiTahsildari can that be in reality that one movie can have more than one genre? I took that in to consideration when adding the sample data...to OP's tables since it's blind guessing without sample data..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could calculate the rating by summing all ratings for a movie in a subquery.  Another subquery could calculate the highest rating per genre.  By joining them together, you'd filter only the top movies per genre:

```
select  *
from    Movie m
join    Genre g
on      g.movieId = m.movieId
join    (
        select  r.mid
        ,       sum(Rating) as SumRating
        from    Rating r
        group by
                r.mid
        ) r
on      r.mid = m.movieId
join    (
        select  g.id as gid
        ,       max(SumRating) as MaxGenreRating
        from    (
                select  r.mid
                ,       sum(Rating) as SumRating
                from    Rating r
                group by
                        r.mid
                ) r
        join    Genre g
        on      g.movieId = r.mid
        group by
                g.id
        ) filter
on      filter.gid = g.id
        and filter.MaxGenreRating = r.SumRating
```

Answer (score 2):

It's really great if you had provided some sample data to match.. Well try this out. Looking at your earlier question this answer is drafted.

[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/36a9f/1)

```
select t.mid, t.sum_rating,
m.title, m.moviepath, g.genres
from (
  select mid, 
         sum(rating) as sum_rating,
         dense_rank() over (order by 
         sum(rating) desc) as rnk
  from rating
  group by mid
) t
left join movie m
on m.movieid = t.mid
left join genre g
on g.movieid = m.movieid
where t.rnk = 1;
```

Results:

```
| MID | SUM_RATING |      TITLE | MOVIEPATH | GENRES |
------------------------------------------------------
|   4 |         37 | Happy days |         a | comedy |
|   4 |         37 | Happy days |         a | RomCom |
```

You may use this alternative as HSQL doesn't support `dense_rank`:

- [SQLFIDDLE DEMO ALTERNATIVE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/36a9f/3)

Query with : `order by desc and top 1`

```
-- alternatively

select t.mid, t.sum_rating,
m.title, m.moviepath, g.genres
from (
  select top 1 mid, 
         sum(rating) as sum_rating
  from rating
  group by mid
  order by sum_rating desc
) t
left join movie m
on m.movieid = t.mid
left join genre g
on g.movieid = m.movieid
;
```

Comment: hsql does not support dense_rank(). Is there a possible solution without dense_rank?

Comment: @maximus is this what you need)I mean the expected results)? Please clarify, take note of the sample data I have used and comment if you need any changes to the sample data and table structure. If so we can get the same with other means for HSQL..

Comment: i just need the mid, title, moviepath

Comment: @maximus I have updated with the alternative method. Please take a look. Also please confirm if ONE MOVIE CAN HAVE MORE THAN ONE GENRE in your design for our own sanity :) So we know the table schema we followed is correct.

Comment: @maximus you may simply remove the `genres` column from `select clause` to make sure that you get the expected results and add `distinct` to the `select claues` as you don't want to return the same data row twice..

Answer (score 0):

Where can we found the count of views? With this tables you can find the highest rated movie by using a query like this:

```
select Movie.movieId, Movie.title, Movie.moviepath
from movie, rating, genre
where
    movie.id = rating.mid and
    movie.id = genre.movieId
order by rating desc
limit 1; // limit is used if you are using MySQL. In other databases you can use suitable sql query.
```

But if you are looking for the most seen movie from most seen genre, you have to have the view count of each movie and each genre inside your tables.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend you using aggregate max on the rating together with group by on genre

`select max(Rating.rating) as max_rating, Genre.genre, Movie.movieId from Movie
    inner join Rating on Movie.movieId = Rating.mid
    inner join Genre on Movie.movieId = Genre.movieId
    group by Genre.genre;`

I am not so sure that this will work 100% since I didn't try it, but I the idea is to use group by. It it ment to be used with aggregates like count, max, min, avg and so on.

I hope that helps